# Diff/merge algorithm to resolve parallel additions

Tags: git, merge, diff

We are in the process of creating a new methodology. Part of it is an implementation pattern which aims a t making possible to parallelize coding.

There are only a few areas for conflicts, and they are meant to be easily resolved. Coders just add blocks of code (constants and methods, and in one case uniformly-looking expressions inside a method).

However we see conflicts we believe are automatically resolvable, but git somehow does not resolve them. Are there options or tools to do it? If not, what algorithm could be used and how to integrate it into git?

I tried the following:

```
git merge -X patience otherbranch
git merge -X patience -X diff-algorithm=patience otherbranch
git merge -X patience -X diff-algorithm=histogram otherbranch
git merge -s resolve  otherbranch
git merge -s renormalize  otherbranch
git merge -X patience -X diff-algorithm=histogram -X renormalize otherbranch
git merge -s subtree  otherbranch
```

Here are some examples of such conflicts:

1. fields added

```html
<<<<<<< feature/issue_105
  public static final String TASK_DESCRIPTION_START = "Task Description: \n";
  public static final String TASK_DESCRIPTION_END =
      "\n End of Task Description \n";
  public static final String DIFF = "Diff: \n";
=======

  public static final String BALANCE_LESS_THAN_USER_BUDGET =
      "The user balance is less than project budget";
>>>>>>> develop
```

2. methods added, diff is confused about boundary

```html
<<<<<<< feature/issue_151
  public static TaskEntity getTaskOne() {
    final TaskEntity taskEntity = get();
    taskEntity.setId(TaskTestData.ID_ONE);
    return taskEntity;
=======
  public static TaskEntity getGrabbedOverThreeDays() {
    final TaskEntity taskEntity = get();
    taskEntity.setStatus(TaskStatusEnum.IN_PROGRESS);
    taskEntity.setGrabDate(TaskTestData.DATE_OLDER_THAN_THREE_DAYS);
    return taskEntity;

>>>>>>> develop
  }
```

3. Only one side is added

```html
<<<<<<< feature/issue_135
=======
  public static MarketUserEntity getRoleProjectManager() {
    final MarketUserEntity marketUserEntity = get();
    marketUserEntity.setUser(UserEntityTestData.getRoleProjectManager());
    return marketUserEntity;
  }


>>>>>>> develop
```

Comment: Set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` and you can see *why* Git is showing these as conflicts. Without that setting all you see are the conflicts themselves, not the merge base upon which the conflicts arise. (Often, it has to do with the diff synchronizing badly.)

Comment: Thanks, but independent of how we got to these conflicts, they should be automatically resolvable based on just the information shown here. I am looking for the way to resolve them.

Comment: Right, but without seeing how they arose in the first place, it's hard to provide a concrete suggestion.

Comment: Both of the branches have added zero or more fields/methods to the file. What else we should know?

Comment: That explains the first two conflicts, but not the third one. The first two conflicts boil down to the fact that Git doesn't know whether to put the left-side added code first, or the right-side added code first, or maybe interleave them. Note that Git decided that the *close brace* was common across both added sections, and *shared* it, so if Git had picked one to go first it would have produced invalid source code either way. The manual resolutions here are up to you (which one goes first, and of course you need two close braces, not one).